# libspotify API: local cache and logout

Tags: spotify

What will **sp_session_logout** do if local host cache is not defined (both "cache_location" and "settings_location" are configured with empty string)? Will it get suspended as there is no cache available for flushing? Or maybe it's not necessary to call **sp_session_logout** at all before terminating the application because the main purpose of using logout call is to flush cache?

Anyway, the reason why I'm trying to disable cache is:

I want to send PCM raw data to standard output instead of alsa driver, and then redirect the data to an audio player. If the cache is enabled, the audio player outputs noise when the cache is empty (first-time play), but outputs music when the cache is not empty (not-first-time play). If the cache is disabled, the audio player outputs music properly.

It's a good idea to have cache enabled, but I don't understand how this cache stuff would impact the audio output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're encountering a problem with your audio code or the fact that you're pushing audio data through standard output. I've worked with many, many libSpotify projects with correctly working caches and I've never seen a problem like this.

Also, `sp_session_logout` disconnects the user from the Spotify AP, so it's important you call it when appropriate.

Comment: Are the following messages printed out on stdout or stderr? These are the messages on screen during playing track.   14:13:24.718 I [ap:1752] Connecting to AP ap.spotify.com:4070

14:13:24.719 I [user_cache:135] UserCache::initiateGetUsers() will query for 1 users

14:13:24.871 I [ap:1226] Connected to AP: 193.182.8.9:4070

14:13:26.182 I [file_streamer_simple.cpp:769] Request for file 2b458ca0a0efbe637f553cd76ed0488d6fdd9371 complete (code: 0)

14:13:26.483 I [file_streamer_simple.cpp:769] Request for file 2b458ca0a0efbe637f553cd76ed0488d6fdd9371 complete (code: 0)

Comment: The printing is done by your code, not libSpotify. Look at how you implemented the `log_message` callback.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps. The noise is gone.